# htaccess redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have a site that I'd like to redirect default requests to `subdir/index.php` and `subdir/$1` for others. I've found some htaccess examples that work (like the following)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```

but it does not work if I do not enter a filename. so if I go to `mydev.com` it gives an error. If I go to `mydev.com/somefile.php` then it works. How can I set this so that if no file is given it defaults to `subdir/index.php` as well as the above?

*edit*
I'd like this to work if I have my site at mydev.com/ or mydev.com/somedir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with default, you mean the domain alone and others is everything else, you can use just these two rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ subdir/index.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/index\.php$
RewriteRule .+ subdir/$0 [R,L]
```

If you want to rewrite only, instead of redirect, leave out the `R`.

Comment: This works if I specify a file but it doesn't if I don't

Comment: @SacLoner What exactly happens, when you enter just `mydev.com`?

Comment: I get a 404, if I enter mydev.com/index.php it works(loads the index.php from the subdir), if I enter mydev.com/subdir it works and obviously if I enter mydev.com/subdir/index.php it works as well.

Comment: @SacLoner Stupid me, I forgot the RewriteBase and the leading slash `/` in the RewriteCond. Please try again.

Comment: This works in all cases with the R.. without the R it works for everything except when I do not specify a file. I get a 404 then. I'm also not sure about the RewriteCond line. I tested it commented and uncommented and everything worked the same (with the R and without the R)

Comment: @SacLoner If the RewriteCond doesn't make a difference, then there's something wrong. When I remove the RewriteCond, I get, as expected, an endless redirect. Either your browser cached some responses or you have additional rules, which interfere.

Comment: The only thing in the .htaccess file is your code. I kinda got it working without the R by removing /index.php from the first RewriteRule. The only caveat is that it adds the subdir/ to the end of the url.

Comment: @SacLoner This is because [`mod_dir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) interferes and does a redirect. I'm still confused, why you don't get an endless redirect loop without the RewriteCond. Anyway, if it works for you the way it is, the better.